# Firebase Storage with Google Actions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-api, firebase-storage, actions-on-google

I am having some issues connecting my firebase storage with my google action. I need to be able to "download" the json files inside in order to be able to read and pick out what a user may need given data that they provide when they call the action.

Below is the code that I currently have, complied from the different APIs and other stackoverflow questions I have found.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const Firestore = require('@google-cloud/firestore');
const firestore = new Firestore();

var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const gcs = storage({projectId: 'aur-healthcare-group'});
const bucket = gcs.bucket('gs://aur-healthcare-group');


admin.storage().bucket().file('aur-healthcare-group/aur_members.json').download(function(errr, contents){
  if(!err){
    var jsObjext = JSON.parse(contents.toString('utf8'));
  }
});
```

The current error I am receiving is *"code":3,"message":"Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause*. When I check the logs I only get the above mentioned message again.

I believe that I am not accessing my firebase storage correctly and have trouble finding a good resource on how to access this correctly. Would somebody be able to give me an example of how to access the storage correctly so I will be able to apply it to my project?

Comment: Welcome to SO. The error you're receiving are extremely vague - imagine how we feel when we don't even know what the errors are! SUPER vague. Please include the errors in the question and tell us what troubleshooting you've done. Did you step through your code line by line and check your vars? Did you ensure either your rules are set correctly or are ensuring your user is authenticated?

Comment: @Jay I added more information to my description that will hopefully will be helpful. I am new to the google actions and firebase sphere so I really just need an outline of how to access the firebase within my action. If you are able to provide that, that would be fantastic!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running in Firebase Functions, you shouldn't need to require the `@google-cloud/storage` dependency directly. Rather, you can get the correctly authenticated storage component via `admin.storage()`

Following that, you shouldn't download the file to your function, as you would be better off reading directly into memory via a `readStream`.

With regards to your existing code error, it may be because you're checking `if (!err)` when the callback variable is `errr`.

I've done this in the past and here's a code snippet of how I achieved it. It's written in Typescript specifically, but I think you should be able to port it to JS if you're using that directly.

```js
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'
import { Bucket } from '@google-cloud/storage';

admin.initializeApp()

const db = admin.firestore()

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket('project-id.appspot.com') // Use your project-id here.

const readFile = async (bucket: Bucket, fileName: string) => {
  const stream = bucket.file(fileName).createReadStream();
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let buffer = '';
    stream.on('data', function(d: string) {
      buffer += d;
    }).on('end', function() {
      resolve(buffer)
    });
  })
}

app.handle('my-intent-handler', async (conv) => {
  const contents = await readArticle(bucket, 'filename.txt')
  conv.add(`Your content is ${contents}`)
})

exports.fulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I ended up with going a different route that was more simple, which I will post as the answer below!

Comment: how to upload file using firebase-admin?

Comment: @ßãlãjî you may want to refer to an article I wrote on this subject: https://fleker.medium.com/uploading-a-photo-to-google-cloud-storage-through-firebase-callable-functions-1a545aea43ac