# Firebase: Get contents of JSON file from storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to "download" the contents of a JSON file that I am storing in my firebase so that I am able to search through it within my google action. I have gotten my code to the point on which I have gotten the file and am unsure of what method to use next. I want something like a toString() method to get the contents of my JSON file into my action.

I have been searching around on https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#get and am guessing that I should use either get() or createReadStream() but there is not much information from there to help guide me on which would be better.

```js
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

const defaultApp = admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault()
});
const database = admin.firestore();
var storage = defaultApp.storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('gs://NAME_OF_BUCKET.appspot.com');
const jsonFile = bucket.file('FILE_NAME.json');
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I have been searching around for an answer for a while now! Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Storage with Google Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67941227/firebase-storage-with-google-actions)

Answer (score 0):

In this case you want either [`download()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download) or `createReadStream()`, which are reasonable for this situation. If the JSON file is relatively small (say < 1MB) `download()` will likely be easier to code against since you won't need to read the stream. `createReadStream()` is good for a scenario where you might be processing a large file in individual chunks (for instance passing it through a compression library on the way to a hard disk).

```
const contents = await jsonFile.download();
console.log(contents);
const parsedContents = JSON.parse(contents);
```

Comment: I tried this with my file (which is about 355 KB) and it still isn't working. It isn't taking any the contents out of the json file, it's just an empty string/json object. Any thoughts?